# Why all the object's keys set out to the values when I am trying to set only one object's key?

Tags: node.js, arrays, object, arrayobject

I have stored some empty objects inside the array means stored some empty objects inside array with key-value pairs generating using the `for-loop`.
Here is how I did:

```
 var events = [], obj, n = 100;
    obj = {
    a: 0,
    b:{},
    "timestamp":new Date()
    };
    
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      events.push(obj);
    }
    events.forEach((item, i) => {
      for(var i=0;i<40;i++)
      item.b["trackID"+i] = 0;
    });
```

So the final events array becomes with containing 100 objects with all keys initialized to zero.

Now I want to set any particular key manually but the problem I am facing is all the keys in all object gets updated with same value whichever key I set. I want to set the value to that respective object key only. Why what's happening wrong here?

For example when  try to set the 5th object suppose the vale **a** and **b** of **trackID25** as **5** and **7** respectively:

```
events[4].a = 5
events[4].b.trackID25 = 7
```

But all the event object's keys a and b (trackIDs) keys are set out to 5 and 7 values respectively.
Why its happening?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript treats object as memory reference so that what you pushed into array is basically same object with pointing same memory address.

You can prevent this problem with copying object.

There are many solution for this problem but what I recommend you to using `lodash.deepClone()` to do so.

In case you prefer native solution, easiest way to copying object is  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`